# Quorum blockchain explorer "connection refused"

Tags: ethereum, quorum

I am trying to explore my transaction and I am using Quorum transaction explorer.
I run the network via vagrant and I executed:

```
NODE_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:2222 docker-compose up
```

I get an error telling me "Connection refused" and I don't know why.
Does anyone have an idea about this problem?